# connect to SQL reporting services on cloud remotely

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a cloud SQL Report Server (Windows Server 2012 R2) and want my customers to remotely access reports via the servers url.  However, I can not get that url to work remote from the VM.  I have TCP/IP and Named Pipes enabled.  Not sure if it's a firewall issue or I set up the server incorrectly.  I've opened up port 1433.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

report server is a web portal for running against SQL server - try opening port 80 (http) and/or 443 (https)

Comment: Still not working.  I opened port 80 and 443 on the inbound.

Comment: I previously had the URL assigned to 8080.  I changed it to port 80 and now I can't even connect locally...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to open the correct port on the cloud management side and then use the VM's public IP address as the URL instead of the Computer's Name.